# ESlint rules conflict

Tags: eslint, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

I'm doing es lint for my project, below is part of the .eslintrc.json

```
{
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "plugins": [
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": ["error"]
    }
}
```

When the lint runs, it captures a warning: ESLint: missing return type on function.(@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types): line number

I guess it's because the `typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types` is inherited from the extends and used before my `typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type` so it's showing up as a warning instead of an error.

The documentation https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-module-boundary-types.md says

> If you wish to make sure all functions have explicit return types, as opposed to only t
> he module boundaries, you can use explicit-function-return-type

is there any way to use explicit-function-return-type first, for all functions no matter exported functions or not? I don't want to disable the `explicit-module-boundary-types` because it also checks parameter type.

Comment: I'm doing it in an Angular project so almost every class/function is exported.

Answer (score 0):

run `npm run lint` in terminal yields correct result. Reports both warning by `explicit-module-boundary-types` and error by `explicit-function-return-type` for same function.

In WebStorm problems panel I could only saw a warning by `explicit-module-boundary-types`